# Reloading an Already Populated AnchorPane

Tags: java, javafx

So I have been working on a JavaFX project where I have a pretty simple work flow. I have several different AnchorPanes that I use, on each the user will fill out some information and go on to the next AnchorPane. Whenever they move on to the next AnchorPane I load the new AnchorPane using the following code.

```
 private Initializable replaceSceneContent(String fxml) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    InputStream in = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(fxml);
    loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
    loader.setLocation(Caster.class.getResource(fxml));

    AnchorPane page;
    try {
        page = (AnchorPane) loader.load(in);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    } 
    Scene scene = new Scene(page, APP_WIDTH, APP_HEIGHT);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.sizeToScene();

    return (Initializable) loader.getController();
}
```

This loads everything fine. But I also have the ability to go back to the previous AnchorPane. Currently this uses the same method, but this is not ideal as it loads a brand new AnchorPane and all the information that user had previously entered is gone. I would like to persist the anchorpanes and reload them and have tried to reload them using code similar to the following

```
 private void replaceSceneContent(AnchorPane page) throws Exception {
    Scene scene = new Scene(page, APP_WIDTH, APP_HEIGHT);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.sizeToScene();
}
```

However, this results in a totally white screen on my application, maybe because I am not loading the FXML again? I need some ideas on how to persist the data the users entered if they want to go back. Any ideas on how to do this well?

Comment: Your approach should work. It's important to make sure you don't have anything added twice to the same scene graph. I would not do it that way, though. If you use a Model-View-Controller architecture and factor the data into a separate model object, your controllers can bind the controls to the data in the model. Then you only have to persist the model and can reload different pages as needed.

Comment: Related example [here](https://github.com/james-d/Shared-Data-Controller)

Comment: Thanks, so simple for some reason I didnt think of just passing the model back and repopulating the values.